# How To Ignore An Character With Random Numbers Using RegEx?

Tags: regex

I am trying to ignore the character `@` with random numbers combined using RegEx.

This is what I don't want to detect:
`@1235`

This is what I want to detect:
`12345`

This what I did so far:

```
(?!@[0-9])([0-9])
```

Comment: Just use `(?<=@)\d+` or `(?<!@)\d+` depending on what you want

Comment: i wont to detect @1235 i wants only to detect 12345

Comment: `^\d+$` or `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)` or `(?<!@)\b\d+`

Comment: take a look: https://regex101.com/r/VbduR9/1

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/hZExNs/1

Comment: You need to use a look*behind* not lookahead, e.g.: [`\b(?<!@)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/4ByvLz/1) or use a *negated character class* before and *capture*: [`(?:[^\d@]|^)(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/XSdzoE/1) if lookbehind is not available in your regex flavor. Mentioning tool/lang is always helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![@\d])\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZoACb/1). *Details*:

- `(?<![@\d])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `@` or a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

See the regex graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to assert that there is no @ to the left with a negative lookbehind `(?<!` instead of a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
\b(?<!@)\d+
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?<!@)` Negative lookbehind, assert not @ to the left
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HiTEgW/1)